# Django rest framework: Remote user not available in middleware - only in view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I`m using the django remote user middleware, and an own middleware `mysupermiddleware`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [    
    ...,
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    'my_project.middleware.mysupermiddleware',
]
```

When a remote user authenticates, it is available in the view. `request.user` shows the username.

But in my middleware, it is not available

```
def mysupermiddleware(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        print (request.user)
```

`request.user` returns `AnonymousUser`

When I print `request.user` in my view, it returns the remote authenticated user.

When I authenticate with `ModelBackend` instead `RemoteUserBackend`, the user is available in middleware and view.

Is this intended? How do I make the remote user available in the middleware? Django version is 3.1.1

**EDIT:**
Found the reason: It is related to rest framework authentication: At [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55937359/django-rest-framework-custom-response-middleware) the user @imposeren states, that

> if you are using something other than rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication as an authentication_class, then request.user is set outside of middlewares (somewhere during View.dispatch)

Does somebody have an idea, on how to use user in middleware regardless?

Comment: Try reordering the middleware in the list?

Comment: Yes: When I set it before `AuthenticationMiddleware`, request.user is not defined. When I set if between `AuthenticationMiddleware` and `RemoteUserMiddleware`, then is is anonymous, too...

Comment: Ok, found the answer, is a duplicate of this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50793212/django-jwt-authentication-user-is-anonymous-in-middleware/65594951
Maybe a mod can mark this as duplicate